# spring boot mvc docker Whitelabel Error

Tags: docker, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I have a spring boot mvc app running on docker container. Container is running perfectly fine but when I try to access app on the browser I get Whitelabel Error Page saying it cannot find /WEB-INF/views/***.jsp. Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.jay.webapp</groupId>
<artifactId>LoginModel</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>LoginModel</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
  </project>
```

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine 
MAINTAINER "***"
COPY LoginModel-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
CMD ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","app.jar"]
```

When I did "java -jar target/LoginModel-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" locally and tried to see it on browser the it worked perfectly without any errors. I only get the error when i tried to run the app on docker container. Where exactly is the mistake?

Answer (score 6):

It seems you're using JSPs, but your app is packaged as a JAR. You should package your application as a WAR. Documentation also mentions that

> Creating a custom error.jsp page won’t override the default view for error handling, custom error pages should be used instead.

Look at [the JSP limitations section in the reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations) for more on this.

Answer (score 3):

You need your project to be a war and a Dockerfile like this

```
FROM tomcat:8.5-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG WAR_FILE
ADD ${WAR_FILE} /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war
RUN sh -c 'touch /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war'
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war" ]
```

and a pom plugin like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
        <buildArgs>
            <WAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.war</WAR_FILE>
        </buildArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

As Brian Clozel said you also need to read the [restrictions on deploying with JSPs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations)

Also be aware of the [dependency changes when deploying as a war](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)

[This example project demonstrates the solution](https://github.com/paulhilliar/spring-boot-docker-jsp-example) (Spring Boot / Docker / JSP / Spring Security)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar condition while I tried to run simple springboot web application in docker-container. I have packaged my application and .jar so the contents of JSP page was not displayed on the browser. I changed the packaging to .war and ran the process again and got the contents displayed in the browser.